# HTML no DB com Laravel 5.8

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

Tenho vários campos numa página que usam `ckeditor`:

```
<label for="PublicoAlvo">Público Alvo</label>
<textarea name="publico_alvo" id="PublicoAlvo" rows="10" cols="80">
    Coloque aqui o Público Alvo do Curso
</textarea>
```

---

```
<script>
   CKEDITOR.replace( 'publico_alvo' );
</script>
```

Ele ta carregando recursos demais e queria apenas o básico: Alinhamento e formatação por exemplo. O caso é que se coloco qualquer formatação, grava no banco e exibe tudo como texto. Tipo esse do Stack para postar perguntas. :)

Exemplo:

```
<p>Esse curso é para pessoas que já estão no ensino <b>superior</b></p>
```

No `controller` to enviando assim:

```
$curso->publico_alvo = $request->input('publico_alvo');
```

Como faço para gravar da forma correta ou mostrar apenas o texto com a página lendo o `html` embutido?

Comment: Ele deve estar gravando correto, na hora de mostrar que você deve utilizar `{!! !!}` ... seu eu não me engano.

Comment: Te ajudou a resposta?

Comment: Ajudou @VirgilioNovic! Muito Obrigado

Comment: agora esta mostrando o texto puro sem HTML. Mas não está interpretando o HTML. Exemplo: Tenho uma lista com 5 opções. Ele lista uma abaixo da outra mas não coloca a marcação da lista. Strong também não está aplicando.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisar usar

```
 {!! $text !!}
```

Mais detalhes em https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data

Comment: agora esta mostrando o texto puro sem HTML. Mas não está interpretando o HTML. Exemplo: Tenho uma lista com 5 opções. Ele lista uma abaixo da outra mas não coloca a marcação da lista. Strong também não está aplicando.